# Xamarin how to access settings and change our device language

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.android

Is there a way to change our mobile device language from coding in xamarin.

Comment: Just asking, but... why? In the app you can get the culture info and act upon it if necessary, which usually isn't, unless you do some manual date parsing or something like that which you shouldn't.

Comment: I don't know how to change my app language if u have a good code pls help me

Comment: @Stefan I don't know how to change my app language if u have a good code pls help me

Comment: Check this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/

Comment: It's about multi language within your app. You can make a default language, and optional ones which can be set to the devices OS language settings.

Comment: @Stefan sir which is easier way to Change language,whole os language Change or a app only,which one have less coding if we do comparisons.

Comment: Changing the OS language is a no-go. 2 options left: make your app multi language as in the article (it seems hard but it's fairly easy and flexible). The other: just write your app in the language which you support. I still have a question: why would you want to change the device's OS language? What will it bring you?

Answer (score 0):

You should not change device's language programatically. Instead of that, I would recommend you to navigate user to the Settings and Language menus to choose wanted language manually.

Comment: How Can i navigate user to settings by coding like animation,like settings will get open automatically when user wants to change language then he can only click on language settings other options must be disabled.this should be happen when user open settings from our app only.